# Joomla make module full width

Tags: html, css, joomla

I want to get a module in joomla 3.4.3 full width.

For example, I have a picture, which should be all over the page.
If I set it to

```
width="100%"
```

it just takes all the space which is usually used by any article, so there are white spaces on both sides, left and right. Some other modules, for example slideshows, usually use the whole width.

How can I use all the space like these modules do?

edit:
I added

```
<div style="margin-left:0px";"padding-left:0px";"margin-right:0px";"padding-right:0px">
    <img src="images/slides/1.jpg" style="width:100%"/>
</div>
```

Which doesn't change anything.
The Image is a placeholder, later there is going to be a google-map why I put the div in.

Index.php:

```
<?php
/**
* @version   $Id: index.php 26163 2015-01-27 17:11:55Z james $
* @author    RocketTheme http://www.rockettheme.com
* @copyright Copyright (C) 2007 - 2015 RocketTheme, LLC
* @license   http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html GNU/GPLv2 only
 *
 * Gantry uses the Joomla Framework (http://www.joomla.org), a GNU/GPLv2 content management system
 *
 */

/* No Direct Access */
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted index access' );
/* Load Mootools */
JHTML::_('behavior.framework', true);
/* Load and Inititialize Gantry Class */
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/lib/gantry/gantry.php');
$gantry->init();
/* Get the Current Preset */
$gpreset = str_replace(' ','',strtolower($gantry->get('name')));
?>
<!doctype html>
<html xml:lang="<?php echo $gantry->language; ?>" lang="<?php echo $gantry->language;?>" >
<head>
<?php if ($gantry->get('layout-mode') == '960fixed') : ?>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=960px">
<?php elseif ($gantry->get('layout-mode') == '1200fixed') : ?>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=1200px">
<?php else : ?>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<?php endif; ?>
<?php /* Head */
    $gantry->displayHead();
?>
<?php /* Force IE to Use the Most Recent Version */ if ($gantry->browser->name == 'ie') : ?>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<?php endif; ?>

<?php
    $gantry->addLess('bootstrap.less', 'bootstrap.css', 6);
    if ($gantry->browser->name == 'ie'){
        if ($gantry->browser->shortversion == 8){
            $gantry->addScript('html5shim.js');
            $gantry->addScript('canvas-unsupported.js');
            $gantry->addScript('placeholder-ie.js');
        }
        if ($gantry->browser->shortversion == 9){
            $gantry->addInlineScript("if (typeof RokMediaQueries !== 'undefined') window.addEvent('domready', function(){ RokMediaQueries._fireEvent(RokMediaQueries.getQuery()); });");
            $gantry->addScript('placeholder-ie.js');
        }
    }
    if ($gantry->get('layout-mode', 'responsive') == 'responsive') $gantry->addScript('rokmediaqueries.js');
?>
</head>
<body <?php echo $gantry->displayBodyTag(); ?>>
    <div id="rt-page-surround">
        <div class="rt-pagesurround-overlay">
            <div id="rt-body-surround">
                <?php /** Begin Header **/ if ($gantry->countModules('header')) : ?>
                <div id="rt-header">
                    <div class="rt-container">
                        <div class="rt-flex-container">
                            <?php echo $gantry->displayModules('header','standard','standard'); ?>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="rt-header-fixed-spacer"></div>
                <?php /** End Header **/ endif; ?>
                <?php /** Begin Slideshow **/ if ($gantry->countModules('slideshow')) : ?>
                <div id="rt-slideshow">
                    <div class="rt-bg-overlay">
                        <?php echo $gantry->displayModules('slideshow','basic','standard'); ?>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <a class="rt-slideshow-scrollbottom" href="#rt-head-anchor" data-scroll><span class="rt-bottom-arrow"></span></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php /** End Slideshow **/ endif; ?>

                <?php /** Begin Head Anchor **/ ?>
                <div id="rt-head-anchor"></div>
                <?php /** End Head Anchor **/ ?>

                <?php /** Begin TopFullWidth **/ if ($gantry->countModules('topfullwidth')) : ?>
                <div id="rt-topfullwidth">
                    <?php echo $gantry->displayModules('topfullwidth','basic','standard'); ?>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
                <?php /** End TopFullWidth **/ endif; ?>
                <?php /** Begin Header Surround **/ if ($gantry->countModules('drawer') or $gantry->countModules('top') or $gantry->countModules('showcase')) : ?>
                <header id="rt-header-surround">
                    <div class="rt-bg-overlay">
                        <?php /** Begin Drawer **/ if ($gantry->countModules('drawer')) : ?>
                        <div id="rt-drawer">
                            <div class="rt-container">
                                <div class="rt-flex-container">
                                    <?php echo $gantry->displayModules('drawer','standard','standard'); ?>
                                    <div class="clear"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php /** End Drawer **/ endif; ?>
                        <?php /** Begin Top **/ if ($gantry->countModules('top-')) : ?>
                        <div id="rt-top">
                            <div class="rt-container">
                                <div class="rt-flex-container">
                                    <?php echo $gantry->displayModules('top-','standard','standard'); ?>
                                    <div class="clear"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php /** End Top **/ endif; ?>

                        <?php /** Begin Showcase **/ if ($gantry->countModules('showcase')) : ?>
                        <div id="rt-showcase">
                            <div class="rt-container">
                                <div class="rt-flex-container">
                                    <?php echo $gantry->displayModules('showcase','standard','standard'); ?>
                                    <div class="clear"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php /** End Showcase **/ endif; ?>
                    </div>
                </header>
                <?php /** End Header Surround **/ endif; ?>

                <?php /** Begin Main Section **/ ?>
                <section id="rt-mainbody-surround">
                    <?php /** Begin Breadcrumbs **/ if ($gantry->countModules('breadcrumb')) : ?>
                    <div id="rt-breadcrumbs">
                        <div class="rt-container">
                            <div class="rt-flex-container">
                                <?php echo $gantry->displayModules('breadcrumb','standard','standard'); ?>
                                <div class="clear"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php /** End Breadcrumbs **/ endif; ?>
                    <?php /** Begin Feature **/ if ($gantry->countModules('feature')) : ?>
                    <div id="rt-feature">
                        <div class="rt-container">
                            <div class="rt-flex-container">
                                <?php echo $gantry->displayModules('feature','standard','standard'); ?>
                                <div class="clear"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php /** End Feature **/ endif; ?>
                    <?php /** Begin Utility **/ if ($gantry->countModules('utility')) : ?>
                    <div id="rt-utility">
                        <div class="rt-container">
                            <div class="rt-flex-container">
                                <?php echo $gantry->displayModules('utility','standard','standard'); ?>
                                <div class="clear"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php /** End Utility **/ endif; ?>
                    <?php /** Begin Expanded Top **/ if ($gantry->countModules('expandedtop')) : ?>
                    <div id="rt-expandedtop">
                        <div class="rt-container">
                            <div class="rt-flex-container">
                                <?php echo $gantry->displayModules('expandedtop','standard','standard'); ?>
                                <div class="clear"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php /** End Expanded Top **/ endif; ?>
                    <?php /** Begin Main Top **/ if ($gantry->countModules('maintop')) : ?>
                    <div id="rt-maintop">
                        <div class="rt-container">
                            <div class="rt-flex-container">
                                <?php echo $gantry->displayModules('maintop','standard','standard'); ?>
                                <div class="clear"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php /** End Main Top **/ endif; ?>
                    <?php /** Begin Main Body **/ ?>
                    <div id="rt-mainbody-wrapper">
                        <div class="rt-container">
                            <?php echo $gantry->displayMainbody('mainbody','sidebar','standard','standard','standard','standard','standard'); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php /** End Main Body **/ ?>
                    <?php /** Begin Main Bottom **/ if ($gantry->countModules('mainbottom')) : ?>
                    <div id="rt-mainbottom">
                        <div class="rt-container">
                            <div class="rt-flex-container">
                                <?php echo $gantry->displayModules('mainbottom','standard','standard'); ?>
                                <div class="clear"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php /** End Main Bottom **/ endif; ?>
                    <?php /** Begin Expanded Bottom **/ if ($gantry->countModules('expandedbottom')) : ?>
                    <div id="rt-expandedbottom">
                        <div class="rt-bg-overlay">
                            <div class="rt-container">
                                <div class="rt-flex-container">
                                    <?php echo $gantry->displayModules('expandedbottom','standard','standard'); ?>
                                    <div class="clear"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php /** End Expanded Bottom **/ endif; ?>
                </section>
                <?php /** End Main Section **/ ?>

                <?php /** Begin FullWidth **/ if ($gantry->countModules('fullwidth')) : ?>
                <div id="rt-fullwidth">
                    <?php echo $gantry->displayModules('fullwidth','basic','standard'); ?>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
                <?php /** End FullWidth **/ endif; ?>

                <?php /** Begin Footer Section **/ if ($gantry->countModules('extension') or $gantry->countModules('bottom') or $gantry->countModules('footer') or $gantry->countModules('copyright')) : ?>
                <footer id="rt-footer-surround">
                    <?php /** Begin Extension **/ if ($gantry->countModules('extension')) : ?>
                    <div id="rt-extension">
                        <div class="rt-container">
                            <div class="rt-flex-container">
                                <?php echo $gantry->displayModules('extension','standard','standard'); ?>
                                <div class="clear"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php /** End Extension **/ endif; ?>
                    <?php /** Begin Bottom **/ if ($gantry->countModules('bottom')) : ?>
                    <div id="rt-bottom">
                        <div class="rt-container">
                            <div class="rt-flex-container">
                                <?php echo $gantry->displayModules('bottom','standard','standard'); ?>
                                <div class="clear"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php /** End Bottom **/ endif; ?>
                    <?php /** Begin Footer **/ if ($gantry->countModules('footer')) : ?>
                    <div id="rt-footer">
                        <div class="rt-container">
                            <div class="rt-flex-container">
                                <?php echo $gantry->displayModules('footer','standard','standard'); ?>
                                <div class="clear"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php /** End Footer **/ endif; ?>
                    <?php /** Begin Copyright **/ if ($gantry->countModules('copyright')) : ?>
                    <div id="rt-copyright">
                        <div class="rt-container">
                            <div class="rt-flex-container">
                                <?php echo $gantry->displayModules('copyright','standard','standard'); ?>
                                <div class="clear"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php /** End Copyright **/ endif; ?>
                </footer>
                <?php /** End Footer Surround **/ endif; ?>
            </div>

            <?php /** Begin Debug **/ if ($gantry->countModules('debug')) : ?>
            <div id="rt-debug">
                <div class="rt-container">
                    <div class="rt-flex-container">
                        <?php echo $gantry->displayModules('debug','standard','standard'); ?>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php /** End Debug **/ endif; ?>

            <?php /** Begin Analytics **/ if ($gantry->countModules('analytics')) : ?>
            <?php echo $gantry->displayModules('analytics','basic','basic'); ?>
            <?php /** End Analytics **/ endif; ?>

            <?php /** Popup Login and Popup Module **/ ?>
            <?php echo $gantry->displayModules('login','login','popup'); ?>
            <?php echo $gantry->displayModules('popup','popup','popup'); ?>
            <?php /** End Popup Login and Popup Module **/ ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php if ($gantry->countModules('slideshow')) : ?>
    <script>
        (function(){
            var width, height = true;

            function initHeader() {
                width = window.innerWidth;
                height = window.innerHeight;

                largeHeader = document.getElementById('rt-slideshow');
                largeHeader.style.height = height+'px';

                document.getElementById('sprocket-features-img-list').style.height= height+'px';

            }

            // Main
            initHeader();
        })();
    </script>
    <?php endif; ?>

</body>
</html>
<?php
$gantry->finalize();
?>
```

Comment: remove margin and padding from body or container which  you are using.

Comment: Do you have a link to the site, so we can have a look at the html?

Comment: The site is currently for testing purposes, so it's only on localhost, I'm sorry

Comment: Can you then maybe show the index.php in your template? Are the image module and the slideshow module in the same position? It feels like both modules have different container div's.

Comment: The width is going to refer to the width of whatever container this is in. So you need to write your css so that it works in the context of whichever of the containers it is in (unclear from your question). Notice for the slideshow `<div id="rt-slideshow">
                    <div class="rt-bg-overlay">`  you might try adding those and see what happens, it may be the second one since 'bg-overlay' sounds promising.

Comment: Ok I will make that an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The width is going to refer to the width of whatever container this is in. So you need to write your css so that it works in the context of whichever of the containers it is in (unclear from your question). Notice for the slideshow 
`<div id="rt-slideshow"> <div class="rt-bg-overlay">` you might try adding those and see what happens, it may be the second one since `'bg-overlay'`sounds promising. –  Elin 8 hours ago